# Unified element access for matrices "v(i)" and cell arrays "v{i}"

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a function which may work with matrices or cell arrays. To get underlying elements I need to access elements of matrices like `v(i)` and elements of cell arrays like `v{i}`. If I access cell array like `v(i)` I will get a 1x1 cell containing element instead of the element itself.

Is there a unified way to access elements in both matrices and cell arrays? For now I have to use a hand-written function for that:

```
function elem = get_element(array, i)
  if iscell(array)
    elem = array{i};
  else
    elem = array(i);
  end
end
```

Note: performance is not an issue.

Comment: ...well, if *performance* is not an issue...<rubs hands together and casts a sinister smile>

Comment: Actually your solution does not look so bad. But won't you want to access `array(2,2)` for example?

Comment: This will be accessed by sequential indexing. I'm iterating from 1 to `numel(array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not convert all inputs to cell arrays and then just use `{}` access?

```
function myFunctionThatGetsMatAndCell( inp )
if ~iscell( inp )
   inp = num2cell( inp );
end
% continue here with only {} access...
%...
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, the other way around:

```
function myFunctionThatGetsMatAndCell(inp)
    if iscell(inp)
       inp = [inp{:}]; end

    % continue here with only () access...
    %...
```

Comment: what happens if some elements of `inp` are not convertable to scalars? what if `inp` has string cells? I thought it would be safer to "cast" to `cell` as it is a more general data structure...

Comment: @Shai: indeed, you'll get errors in those cases. The OP is trying to treat two data types as if they are the same, that's just asking for trouble. S/he seems to be trying to do something where it is guaranteed that these conditions for the cell are true. In case they are not, my solution [fails faster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) than yours.

Comment: Thanks for the other suggestion! However, I primarily work with cell arrays with content not convertible to scalars and sometimes with matrices. So the answer by Shai is what I need.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis have you considered `inp = {1566,2432,3666,'f',5.5}`?

Comment: Perhaps even more scary than the cases that cause an error: `inp = cell(2,1); inp{2}=1`